# Как в axios указать что ожидается json или blob?

Tags: javascript, post, get, axios

Как `axios` в `get` или `post` запросе указать, что в случает успеха я ожидаю `blob`, а в случае ошибки `json`?

```
getApiReport(){
  return axios.get("/api/report/box_report", {
    params: {
      date_from: this.date_from,
      date_to: this.date_to,
      client_ids: this.selected_clients,
    },
    responseType: 'blob',
  });
},
```

Обработка ответа:

```
getReport() {
  this.btn_loading = true;
  this.getApiReport().then(response => {
    // В response - blob
    this.dialog(false);
    this.outputBlobOnHref(response.data, response.headers);
  }).catch(errors => {
    // В errors - json
    console.log(errors.response.data);
    // this.showErrors(errors.response.data.messages, true, 7000);
  }).finally(() => {
    this.btn_loading = false;
  });
},
```

Comment: `responseType` указывает тип данных, которыми сервер будет отвечать: `arraybuffer`, `document`, `json`, `text`, `stream`, `blob` (последний только для браузеров) - оно, нет?

Comment: @РустамГимранов это я знаю, как у меня указано, сейчас добавлю в вопрос. Но проблема в том, что в случае ошибки сервер возвращает `json`.

Comment: `.catch(error => error.response.data.text()).then(data => console.log(JSON.parse(data)));` - только такие предположения